# unknow erlang syntax

Tags: erlang

In the file of "jobs_info.erl" of github project "jobs", it contains the following codes:

```
pp(L) when is_list(L) ->
    [pp(X) || X <- L];
pp(X) ->
    case '#is_record-'(X) of %<=========What's meaning of '"#is_record-'?
    true ->
        RecName = element(1,X),
        {RecName, lists:zip(
            '#info-'(RecName,fields), %<=======what's meaning of ''#info-'?
            pp(tl(tuple_to_list(X))))};
    false ->
        if is_tuple(X) ->
            list_to_tuple(pp(tuple_to_list(X)));
           true ->
            X
        end
    end.
```

What's the expression of `'#is_record-'` and `''#info-'`?
"is_record" may be refered to erlang:is_record?
But what's "'#info-'"?

Comment: You might find this worth looking at: https://github.com/esl/parse_trans/blob/master/src/exprecs.erl#L116

Comment: These are just "funny" function names. In erlang a function name must be an *atom* and as @Mille has pointed out that if by surrounding the characters in an atom with `'` you can basically have any character in the name. So `'#is_record-'` and `'#info-'` are just atoms. They have no intrinsic connection to either records or anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Kemal points out have a look at the method declaration at [github.com/esl/parse_trans/blob/master/src/exprecs.erl#L116](http://github.com/esl/parse_trans/blob/master/src/exprecs.erl#L116).

If it is the `'` that confuses you, remember that a function name in Erlang is an atom and that an atom needs to start with a lower-case letter and if it does not it should be surrounded by `'`. Check the [docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66663) for more info.